# Flutter error : Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+, Status code 502

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle, bintray

Looks like Bintray library is down and I am not able to build my app. I tried a lot of solutions but none them worked.
A similar github issue is there which is already closed without any proper help.
Github link: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/94400

**This is the error I am getting :**

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :location
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
> > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
> > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

**android\build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
//        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2'
        }
//        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.1-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

** flutter doctor -v **

[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1348], locale en-US)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at C:\Users\PC\Documents\src\flutter
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (5 months ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
• android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6842174)

[√] VS Code (version 1.62.3)
• VS Code at C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.25.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
• Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 96.0.4664.93
• Edge (web)                  • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.43

• No issues found!

Comment: Update my question, try this [my question ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70309075/problems-in-android-repository-flutter-tensorflow-lite-by-bintray-502?noredirect=1#comment124315942_70309075)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All my codes were right, the only problem was the location package which I replaced with geolocator package. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Only change!!

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+'
```

to

```
api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
```

Comment: You should probably mention where to change this. See [this answer on a duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319873/930640) for details.

Comment: I change it and it works for me as well. I changed it in Flutter SDK
@Magnus
/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/location-3.2.4/android/build.gradle