# Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.> Unable to load Maven meta-data from

Tags: android, flutter

I'm using flutter project within that in android code I get following error.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
> Required by:
> project :app > project :location
> > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.

my app level build.gradle file is as below,

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '3'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.test.appname"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

android level buid.gradle file,

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
//        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: check in SDK tools that you have the Google Play Services installed or not...

Comment: I installed but still gives same error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70306564/flutter-error-could-not-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-location solved issue

Comment: It seems like code doesn't have issue with google services but it has issue with location: ^3.0.2 plugin added in pubspec.yaml file just comment it then execute pub get & run app