# Please help me with dependencies problem in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Can someone help me with dependencies issues? I'm stuck here and I can't get my app started.

```dart
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:{strictly 16.0.1}.
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app                                                   
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebasedynamiclinks:firebase_dynamic_links:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.8' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:{strictly 16.0.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.0.1
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
                                                                        
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1.
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.8
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebasedynamiclinks:firebase_dynamic_links:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.8' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:{strictly 16.0.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.0.1
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
                                                                        
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0.
     Required by:                                                       
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'io.flutter.plugins.firebasedynamiclinks:firebase_dynamic_links:1.0-SNAPSHOT' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.8' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1'
           Constraint path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:{strictly 16.0.1}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 16.0.1
           Dependency path 'android:app:unspecified' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:20.0.1' --> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-interop:17.0.0' --> 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.0.0'
                                                                        
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

This is what my build.gradle looks like, I've tried so many times to change the gradle here, but nothing really works:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    // implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

Comment: check this link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166663/could-not-get-play-services-location-maven-metadata-xml-received-status-code/70360614#70360614"

Comment: check the documentation on firebase messaging. I had error to put "implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.1'" : https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/overview