# Flutter google version issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gg9xv.png)

There is an app in Flutter version 1.2. I ran this with FVM. It works for iOS but not for Android. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319873/12999567

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work

Comment: You may have tried in the wrong place. Your issue is related to OneSignal. So you need to fix it under the OneSignal package.