# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources' flutter

Tags: flutter

I am getting below error while building app for first time. I have cloned the repository. I have tried upgrading gradle version to latest but didn't helped. Can anyone help me with this.

below is the exception shown

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:+.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Failed to list versions for androidx.core:core-ktx.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin camera...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'camera'.
> SDK location not found. Define location with sdk.dir in the local.properties file or with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s

Exception: The plugin camera could not be built due to the issue above.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166663/could-not-get-play-services-location-maven-metadata-xml-received-status-code

Comment: Hi i solved issue by updating minSdkVersion from 16 to 21