# Error when running app on virtual machine in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am fairly new to android studio so please excuse my incompetence. Two days ago I deleted android studio and re-downloaded it and now the emulator refuses to work. This is the error message that I am receiving:

https://controlc.com/105d979d

I have tried completely uninstalling android studio including the .gradle and sdk files and .m2 and .android files. I also tried to reinstall older version of android studio. I have been searching google for hours and nothing is working. Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319873/13843688

1. In the Project tool window (where your files are listed), scroll all the way down until you find `Flutter Plugins`. If you don't see it, make sure that Project is selected in the dropdown at the top of the Project tool window.
2. Open `Flutter plugins`, find `location-4.0.0` and open it (you might have a different version number after `location-`, that's fine).
3. Open the file `location-4.0.0/android/build.gradle`
4. Find the line `api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+'`
5. Change it to `api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'`. If your editor says that the file does not belong to your project, select `"I want to edit this file anyway"`.