# Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:20.4.1 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, stripe-payments, jcenter

I am getting following error while trying to build Android app in Flutter project

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:20.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :stripe_android
      > Could not resolve com.stripe:stripe-android:20.4.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/stripe-android/20.4.1/stripe-android-20.4.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/stripe-android/20.4.1/stripe-android-20.4.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
   > Could not resolve com.stripe:financial-connections:20.4.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :stripe_android
      > Could not resolve com.stripe:financial-connections:20.4.1.
         > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/financial-connections/20.4.1/financial-connections-20.4.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/stripe/financial-connections/20.4.1/financial-connections-20.4.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter_stripe:
```

android/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I think the problem is related to `jcentre()` but not using `jcentre()` in my app or `stripe` is also not using it but still I am getting the error.

Build just retries again and again but always the same error.

[tried this thread but no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70166663/could-not-get-play-services-location-maven-metadata-xml-received-status-code/70319873#70319873)

Comment: Looking at the other thread you referenced, and based on that it does seem like the concern may be the unpinned versions being used here: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/packages/stripe_android/android/build.gradle. I would recommend raising this as an issue in that repo so the devs can help troubleshoot or determine if your environment is missing an expected configuration.

Comment: did you ever resolve this ? we are seeing same issue

Comment: same issue with me

Comment: Did anyone find solution, was working fine yesterday but getting same issue today

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get through it by manipulating the second or third-section of the  versions in the error which could not be resolved.

- In the project files, scroll down to **External Libraries** then **Flutter Plugins**.
- find your **strip_android-'your version'** then **android/build.gradle**
- Scroll down to the **dependencies** section then find packages ending with **+** in there version. (Mostly the one in the error log).
- Remove the **+** and try setting it to **0** or decrease the second version number by **one** but make sure to remove the **+**.

In **Flutter_stripe: 5.0.0** my error was **20.9.+** then convert it to **20.9.0** and it worked.

In **Flutter_stripe: 6.0.0** my error was **20.12.+** then convert it to **20.11.0** and it worked while **20.12.0** did not work.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, I solved it by simply **upgrading the version of gradel**.
I added `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'` to build.gradle at the project level and I added `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip` to gradle.wrapper.properties.

Comment: most projects have these settings already.